# How to get the initial start-time and end-time for Airflow DAG, including all tasks

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver, airflow-api

How can I get the start and end time of the [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) in overall, which includes all the tasks (which is the initial task start time and end time of the last task)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Airflow API:

For DAGs: `api/v1/dags/{dag_id}/dagRuns`

For tasks: `api/v1/dags/{dag_id}/dagRuns/{dag_run_id}/taskInstances`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but over here again the data needs to be collected and required data needs to be sorted. Which again requires more set of coding.

Comment: Well I was able to get **time=context.get("task_instance").duration** time for the overall tasks within one dag.